# Oracle Spool Script Output To Table

Tags: oracle, spool

Is there any way to spool .sql script output to table?

One workaround I can think is to spool to filesystem by creating dynamically an insert-statements script with the feedback and then run this against your schema.

However, I would like to know if there is a better solution to spool directly into table or a system table which already exists and stores this info (for example script filepath, execution date, execution results ; `1 row inserted`, `commit` etc...

Thanks

Comment: It's a better way to audit any activity by means of a server by turning on Audit for instance. There is no way you can spool sql*plus messages into a table directly.

Comment: @user1651063 How long do you intend for this data to persist for, and how are you going to be manipulating it after that? As Robert mentioned, PLSQL may be a better solution. Or I'd suggest maybe using temporary tables.

Answer (score 1):

Write the spool file to a directory where you have defined an Oracle Directory. 
Write a procedure that takes a filename and a directory name as input and that writes the file as a CLOB into a table.

```
spool test.txt

your code

spool off

exec write_spool_file_to_database_proc('test.txt','YOURDIR');
```

Take a look at this on how to write a file into a table CLOB column.

http://www.roeptoeter.nl/?p=254

Comment: +1 for link to code.  As a thought experiment, assume the database goes down.  How and where will the resulting connection errors be logged?

Comment: It will still be on the filesystem ;-)

Comment: I realize that some may not share my view, but this is one reason I prefer logging to flat files instead of trying to log to the database. In unusual or abnormal conditions, which is one of the principal reasons I want something logged, you have to hunt for the appropriate file anyways (and hope it hasn't been overwritten by subsequent actions, etc, blah). I've found it's simpler to just append text to a flat file.

Comment: @Bob I totally agree. When logging you should not depend on the technology stack you are logging about (or a least as little as possible).